# Could not install windows feature IIS

Tags: iis, windows-10, windows-10-desktop

I tried to reinstall iis on my windows 10 system through Control Panel\Programs and Features\ Turn Windows features on or off but after uninstalling it there is a problem with installing iis again.

Here are screenshots with all errors I'm facing at the moment:
[image: windows feature install message]

[image: IIS main screen]

[image: IIS error message when trying to open Sites tab]

[image: IIS error message when trying to open Application Pools tab]

In folder Windows/System32/inetsrv/config I recreated file named ApplicationHost.config

here is the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.applicationHost>
        <applicationPools>
            <add name="DefaultAppPool" />
            <applicationPoolDefaults>
                <processModel identityType="NetworkService" />
            </applicationPoolDefaults>
        </applicationPools>
        <customMetadata />
    <listenerAdapters>
        <add name="http" />
    </listenerAdapters>
    <log>
        <centralBinaryLogFile enabled="true" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
        <centralW3CLogFile enabled="true" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
    </log>
    <sites>
        <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="DefaultAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
    <webLimits />
</system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone had something like that before me and was able to run IIS again without reinstalling entire system from scratch?

If any information needed please do not hasitate to ask in comment section.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is an invalid file you showed. Delete it and reinstall. IIS installer should give a new one.

Comment: @LexLi after deleting file and trying to reinstall getting the same message presented on first screen from post

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/installation-issues/troubleshooting-iis-7x-installation-issues If the article cannot help you either, you need to do an in-place install of Windows.

Comment: @LexLi Does it also apply for iis 8.5  on windows 10 it's 8.5?

Comment: Microsoft is lazy to update all posts to include IIS 10, but it does apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@LexLi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) and links provided by him i was able to find out what caused the issue.

[Main Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/installation-issues/troubleshooting-iis-7x-installation-issues)

[Second one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2010/05/26/iis7-x-a-common-mistake-when-reinstalling-iis-7-x-errors-0x80070490-and-0x80070002/)

[And last which point the way to uninstall Windows Process Activation Service in Windows 10 pro not server one](https://web.archive.org/web/20190201074831/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/930911/the-windows-process-activation-service-feature-is-not-turned-off-when)

Just to be sure I uninstalled:
Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core

I hope this answer would help someone in future.

Thanks again [@LexLi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) for assistant.
Cheers!